# Can I plant Escallonia Apple Blossom as a hedge in partial shade?

Tags: shrubs, optimal-conditions, shade

Is Escallonia Apple Blossom shrub suitable for planting as a hedge in a North facing cornish wall?  The site is windy, coastal and in the shade of the house.

The Royal Horticultural Society says they are okay for North facing, partial shade.

https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=748

Comment: Hi Will! I see you've been around the SE network for a long time, it's nice to meet you over here! Do you have a picture of your wall and area we could see? If not, would you describe, or add a link to your type of cornish wall? It's something I've never heard of, but when I looked on line, different types of things came up. Also, what's your average temperature range? Is your wind fairly constant and chilly? If you can just add those details into the question, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial shade isn't a problem, though if its more than partial you may find flowering is reduced. However, you may want to reconsider your choice - Escallonia Leaf Spot is a fungal infection of these plants and there is no effective treatment for it. The disease is widespread in the West country because of higher precipitation levels, such that many people are removing their plants, so it might be worth checking whether other people in the area have or have had this problem. More info here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=108

Comment: the fungus doesn't sounds great.  thanks for the heads up.  In terms of shade, I know partial is ok, I'm not sure if the site is partial or full, can't find a definition anywhere.

Comment: @Will full shade means it never gets any sun, at any time of day or year, but depending what surrounds the area, even north facing gardens get sun in summer, though it doesn't usually reach the walls of the house

Comment: ok thanks thats helpful.  not full shade then.